# homework dup2 function

Tags: c++, unix, unistd.h

I have a question on a homework assignment with the following code:

```
dup2(fd,0);
dup2(fd,1);
dup2(fd,2);
if(fd>2)
    close(fd);
```

It says,

> "To see why the if test is needed, assume fd is 1 and draw a picture
>   of what happens to the three descriptor entries and the corresponding
>   file table entry with each call to dup2. Then assume fd is 3 and draw
>   the same picture."

I was wondering if I could get some help on this because I am pretty lost.

Can anyone give me a quick tutorial on this material because I'm having a hard time finding it in my book and online. Thanks.

Comment: what is your question? You don't want to close stdout or stderr!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch why dont u write that as answer? it is correct.

Comment: I was wondering if I could just get an explanation of what the question is asking. I'm having a hard time understanding the dup2 function and when it talks about "the corresponding file table entry".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - but if you close stderr, you won't get any more errors! :P

Answer (score 3):

if fd is 3, it will close fds 0, 1, 2 which would have been originally pointing to stdin, stdout, stderr respectively, and create 3 copies of fd: 0, 1, 2 all pointing to the same destination as the fd 3. now you don't need 3 so you close it because you already have 0, 1, 2 pointing to where 3 was pointing and you don't plan on using 3 any more.

if fd is 1, it will close fds 0, 2 which would have been originally pointing to stdin, stderr respectively, and create 2 copies of fd: 0, 2 all pointing to the same destination as the fd 1 (stdout). now you do need 1 pointing to stdout because the rest of your program plans on using 1 as stdout, so you don't close fd in that case.

thus you need the if statement because in one case you need to close an fd that you don't plan to use, and in the other case you do not need to close the fd that you do plan to use.

man page: http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2

Answer (score 1):

First, loop up what the `dup2()` function does, e.g. http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/dup2.3.asp. That link tells you that `dup2()`  "duplicates open file descriptor onto another file descriptor, " and that "If successful, `dup2()` returns a nonnegative integer; namely, the duplicated file descriptor, which is the lowest available descriptor."

Then, you'll want to draw the file descriptors on a piece of paper (just draw `fd`, `0`, `1`, `2` spaced out on a piece of paper). This will be the initial state of the file descriptors you have before the first `dup2()` call. That is, you have three file descriptors.

Then redraw the file descriptors after each call to `dup2()`. At the end, if `fd > 2`, you're closing one of the file descriptors.

I'm no expert on the `dup2()` function, but this is how I would go about it. Just read that webpage carefully so that you know how the function works (any maybe verify that the information is correct by checking out a few more references).

Good luck!

Comment: rtfwb ;p (just pulling your leg; nice of you to help out)